# How to check feature is true on different environments in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, environment

I am using different environments in angular, stored into the environments folder, like:

```
environment.ts
environment.dev.ts
environment.prod.ts
```

In the environment.ts file, I have:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  environment: 'Development',
  advanced: {
    features: true
  }
};
```

I want to show a div element in page only if the environment has this advanced feature equal to true. I was thinking of doing :

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
export class AdvancedComponent implements OnInit {
  advancedFeatures:boolean;
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.advancedFeatures= environment.advanced.features;

    if (this.advancedFeatures){
      console.log("true");
    }
    else {
      console.log('false');
    }
  }

}
```

Is this enough for hiding or showing a div element if the environment is dev or prod? Is this a good approach of the advanced feature from environment or should I somehow import all environments into this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `environment.ts` is the default config that's used when you import the environment file.

And the reason Angular is able to pick the right environment file during build is by utilizing a `fileReplacements` section in its config settings ([see ng docs](https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-target-specific-file-replacements)). That way it ensures that you use the correct `environment.advanced.features` value in your code.

Similar to the `prod` version in `fileReplacements`, you could define any kind of setting (ie. `dev or testing`) and refer to the corresponding environment file.

As for the viability of your approach-- personally I prefer using access roles to define which pages a user can see but I don't see any particular disadvantages of your approach either.

Comment: Thanks Aldin. Bottom line, in code always import this file - `environment.ts`, angular will replace the content to `environment.prod.ts` during build if the `fileReplacements` is defined (for me it was defined automatically after project creation)